# Best way to implement custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I am attempting to implement a custom UITableView cell matching the attached screenshot in iOS 7+. I am going to use AutoLayout and hand code the layout,subviews etc. There is going to be a distance indicator, a like count and a comment count that both have a small icon beside them. Would it be best to implement these as UIViews containing a UILabel and UIImageView?

There will also be a bookmark button visible in the upper right, that should be a UIButton. Any advice appreciated.

[image]

Comment: > these as UIViews containing a UILabel and UIImageView - just use UIButton with image and label instead. Will be easier to layout.

Comment: @slxl Thanks for the tip! Will the image be to the left of the label?

Comment: sure. also probably you will be required to adjust their relative position. easy article for beginners to understand insets is http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2012/07/youre-doing-it-wrong-2-sizing-labels.html